# find_all in beautiful soup with regular expression

Tags: regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

images = beautifulsoup.find_all('img', {'src':re.compile('.jpg')})
I just want to know what does the above line of code will do

Comment: Just run it and see the result!

Answer (score 0):

It finds all "img" tags in the declared soup and returns the urls to each image.